# how to add a slice of placeholder tensor to 1 in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In order to have oneHot encoding I use this code:

```
self.Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 1])
self.YY=tf.one_hot(self.Y,depth=5) gives us
```

given y=2, it gives me [0 0 1 0 0].

Now I want to have an encoding like onehot, but with all ones after index y. For example, given y=2 then it should give [0 0 1 1 1].

By the way, I do not want to do this outside of tensorflow.

Comment: Try `tf.cast(tf.logical_not(tf.sequence_mask(Y,maxlen=5)),tf.int32)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tf.range()` function to return a sequence of integers up to your max value then use the `<=` comparison to compute to your desired result.

So for example, with the tensor in your example, `[2]`, we could just do:

```py
tf.cast(Y <= tf.range(5),tf.int32)
```

to produce the desired result: `[0,0,1,1,1]`.

It also 'broadcasts' in the way we'd expect with a a batch of values. Given say a batch size of 5 so you have a `batch_Y` with value something like: `[[1], [0], [1], [4], [2]]` then:

```py
tf.cast(batch_y <= tf.range(5),tf.int32)
```

produces the correct output:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted. intelligent.